# How to create a similar template like this for errors?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I've seen in several sites where publish some images of their applications using a style for ErrorTemplate like this:

[image]

Do you know where can I find it?

Comment: Is this really WPF or is it a website?

Comment: What you need to do is look up using Adorners, that's how you do it.  I don't have any specific code (and it would probably quite a significant amount if I did), but that's how it's done.

Comment: It looks like the error template is just a red `Border` around the `TextBox`, and a `Popup` containing the error text. The `Popup` looks like some kind of panel with a `CornerRadius` to make it round, a `DropShadow` effect, a `Fill` color, and `Path` w/ `Fill` for the < shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks much like [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx). 
The idea is to draw something above/near the control where its defined which is not also affected by transformations applied to scene.

For example you can define a Adorner in `Style` of your `TextBox`.

Something like this (a pseudocode):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                       ........
                       ........
                       <AdornerDecorator Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                           .........
                           .........
                       </AdorenrDecorator>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

A complete example (for `ScrollViewer`, but the ides is the same) can find  [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e060205e-5bfc-4f21-bf80-dfa55c44eb8a)

Answer (score 5):

I just whipped one up, took a little tinkering but it works in my WPF test application (using .Net 4.0).  I actually wanted something like this for an application I'm working on, so your question was a convenient excuse to make one. =)

This code uses the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attached property to create an `ControlTemplate` that sets up a red border to outline the validated control, and then a `Popup` that contains the error message for the control.  I had to get the error message from the validated control's `ToolTip` property because the `TextBox` inside the template didn't seem to have access to the `Validation` class itself.

The popup error message closes when the validated control looses focus, and reappears (if there is an error) when it gains focus again.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Here's the gist code: https://gist.github.com/1672789

I'm open to any comments or improvements anyone would offer.

Comment: Cool, but the popup doesn't move with the window when it is dragged